# updating nested data in d3 when using each

Tags: jquery, arrays, d3.js, nested, each

My data updates every 30 seconds and getting his data from a neo4j datebase. I dont know how to update the tables when using ***each***. It seems like, there are no enter, update, exit sections.

```
                var box = d3.select("#silencer").selectAll(".ursa")
                    .data(fraung);


                    box.enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "ursa")
                    .each(function(d) {

                        d3.select(this)
                        .append("svg")                  
                        .attr("class", "invoker")                           
                        .each(function(d) {


                            d3.select(this).append("svg:image")
                                .attr("xlink:href", "images/Fraung.png")
                                .attr("x", "0")
                                .attr("y", "0")
                                .attr("width", "100")
                                .attr("height", "100")
                                .append("title")
                                .text(function(d) {return (d.name)});   

                        });

                    d3.select(this).append("div")
                        .attr("class", "chen")              
                        .each(function(d) {


                            d3.select(this).append("table")
                            .attr("class", "tabelle")
                            .each(function(d) {
                                d3.select(this).append("tbody")
                                .each(function(d) {

                                    d3.select(this).append("tr")
                                    .text(function(d) {return("Name: ")})
                                    .attr("class", "key")
                                    .each(function(d) {
                                        d3.select(this).append("td")
                                        .text(function(d) {return (d.name)});
                                    });

                                }); 
                            });
                        }); 

                });  

            box.exit().remove();
```

my data looks like that

[image]

---

Ok I fixed my problem by breaking up each selection, instead of using ***each***

```
                var box = d3.select("#silencer").selectAll(".ursa").data(fraung);

                    box.enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "ursa")

                    box.exit().remove();

                    var kreis = box.selectAll(".chen")
                    .data(function (d) {return [d];});

                    kreis.enter()
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "chen")  ;

                    kreis.exit().remove();

                    var kreuz = kreis.selectAll(".tabelle").data(function (d) { return [d];});

                    kreuz.enter()
                            .append("table")
                            .attr("class", "tabelle")

                    kreuz.exit().remove();                      

                    var dreieck = kreuz.selectAll("tbody").data(function (d) {return [d];});

                                dreieck.enter()
                                .append("tbody");       

                    dreieck.exit().remove();

                    var viereck = dreieck.selectAll(".key").data(function (d) {return [d];});

                                    viereck.enter()
                                    .append("tr")                       
                                    .text(function(d) {return("Model: ")})
                                    .attr("class", "key")   ;   

                    viereck.exit().remove();

                    var cc = viereck.selectAll("td").data(function (d) { return [d]});

                        cc.text(function(d) {return (d.model)});

                        cc.enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) {return (d.model)});


                    cc.exit().remove();
```

Comment: The way your code is written you'll get `div` with a **single** `table` with a **single** `tr` with a **single** `td` for each row in your data (and it'll be a mal-formed table at that).  The `enter` and `exit` is happening at that first `div` level.  I'm not sure what you are asking or what you are expecting your code to do...

Comment: I want my Code, to update the data in the tables. I can add and delete Objects, but their data don't updates